# How to deploy django on AWS elastic beanstalk with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried a lot of tutorials including aws beanstalk official django deployment document. There is always some kind of error. eg:

1. none of my requirements.txt packages get installed on ec2. When i ssh to ec2 I see that Django==2.1.1 is not an available option that for installation.
2. Unable to connect to postgresql DB from ec2, but could connect from
   my local machine, inspite of having added ec2 public IP4 to the
   security group. It connects when I add ec2 security group ID to rds inbound though.

I spent many days trying to fix individual problem but still the overall attempt has been a frustrating failure. I know there must be lot of rookie aspiring django+AWS developers like me who would greatly appreciate a **comprehensive** tutorial that just works with python 3.6 instead of having to put pieces together or use third party services.

Thanks

Comment: Which image did you used to create EC2 instance? Also, are you using Docker?

Comment: I used python platform. I did not choose any particular image so it was default Linux AMI